# Impossible to index an upload folder with 10k files

Tags: directory, ftp, uploads

I have a WP installation which has a very large uploads folder with a bit more than 10k files. At the time we unset year/month folder organization and now we have huge problems to download or backup the folder as it is not accessible any longer. The serve

I've tested a couple of ftp client (ftp zilla and SMART FTP), my built-in host ftp application and several WP ftp plugins. Nothing seem to offer reliable results. I've managed to display once or twice the directory listing but no operation was possible. The server goes time out systematically and therefore it is impossible to download one single file from this folder.

According to my research, the issue would come of folder index limitation. Therefore I am looking for a script/method/plugin that would:

- EITHER, force the download of every files contained in upload folder. 
  Already try the windows CMD and it didn't work;
- OR, cut down down dramatically the number of file by folder by reorganizing in bulk my upload folder (of 10k files) in a fresh %year%/%month% folder structure and rename all associated links in the database.

I have been searching for a couple of hour and it seems there's no alternative than asking a manual backup the host company.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Axel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axel,

I would recommend getting an SSH connection to your host. This means that you'll get a command prompt that you can issue commands. Something like this if you have a linux server:

[image]

... once you have that, simply browse to your directory and gzip/compress the entire uploads directory:

```
tar -zcf mybackup.tar.gz uploads/
```

Then once that gz file is created, you can either download it via normal HTTP, or via you FTP client.

Comment: Hi GavinR, Thank you very much. It worked like a charm. SO proved again how powerful it is.